# Throttling Apache CXFclients

Tags: spring, web-services, apache, cxf

We are implementing client webservices using the Apache CXF wsdl2java maven plugin.

At our site we receive requests in webapp and for some requests we need to retrieve data using webservices. For these webservices we have generated the clients.

Now we want to throttle the calls to these webservices.
Is there something out of the box to support this.

Note that we are also using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

One practice to maintain Quality of Service for Web Services is to proxy the web service through an ESB, and have the ESB manage service request throttling. The advantage to this is that the web service remains concerned with the service delivery, and the QoS concerns are not muddying the waters.

[Here is a description of functionality an ESB brings to the table.](http://www.jboss.org/jbossesb/resources/WhatIsAnESB)